# React Native Redux prevent action from being repeated twice in 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a React Native Redux application and I've run into an issue where I'm struggling to figure out the cleanest most effective solution.

I have a reducer which manages a modal like this:

```
import {
  OPEN_CHORDS_MODAL,
  CLOSE_CHORDS_MODAL
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  chordsModalIsOpen: false
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case OPEN_CHORDS_MODAL:
      return { chordsModalIsOpen: action.payload };
    case CLOSE_CHORDS_MODAL:
      return { chordsModalIsOpen: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Then I have my actions for the modal here:

```
import { FacebookAds } from 'expo';

import {
  OPEN_CHORDS_MODAL,
  CLOSE_CHORDS_MODAL
} from './types';

export const openChordsModal = () => ({
  type: OPEN_CHORDS_MODAL,
  payload: true
});

export const closeChordsModal = () => {
  FacebookAds.InterstitialAdManager.showAd('328225604270934_328677554225739')
    .then(console.log('Intestitial Ad shown'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Interstitial Ad Error', err));
  return { type: CLOSE_CHORDS_MODAL, payload: false };
};
```

Basically I'm looking at the `closeChordsModal` action.

I currently have an interstitial ad which displays every time the modal closes. This works great but I want to improve the user experience by limiting the amount of times the interstitial ad pops.

I want to make sure that once the ad shows for the first time, it doesn't show again for at least another 2 minutes.

i.e. The user opens and closes the modal, the ad appears (currently what's happening). Then the user opens and closes the modal again, if it has been within 2 minutes since the last close modal action, just close the modal, Otherwise close the modal and show the interstitial ad.

How can I accomplish that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the solution involves `Date` to wait for the 2 minutes, we can't do that in the reducer, because reducers have to be pure, no side effect or external dependency (yes, time is an external dependency).

In your action, every time you call `closeChordsModal` you save the current time + 2 minutes.

```
const doNotShowAnythingUntil = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 2*60*1000);
```

then every time you call that action again you check that

```
if( new Date() < doNotShowAnythingUntil ) { do nothing }
```

In this way, your reducer is still pure and the action is taking care of the behaviour.

Code example:

```
import ...
import ...

export ...

let expirationDate;

export const closeChordsModal = () => {
    if(!expirationDate 
       || new Date() > expirationDate
    ) {
        expirationDate = new Date(
            new Date().getTime() + 2*60*1000
        );
        FacebookAds.InterstitialAdManager.showAd....
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool I understand what you mean but how to I implement that in my `closeChordsModal` action?  Because I need it to actually show the first time.

Comment: Thanks @maxgallo :)

Answer (score 0):

React Native [implements](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html) the browser timers. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
export class ModalContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    blockAds: false,
  };

  enableAds() {
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          blockAds: false,
        }),
      , 120000
    );
  }

  displayFacebookAds = () => {
    if(!this.state.blockAds) {
      *Your code to dispatch FacebookAd action*
      this.setState({ blockAds: true });
      this.enableAds();
    }
  }
}
```